# Ошибка CS0161 '"Program.GetMinX(int, int, int)": не все ветви кода возвращают значение

Tags: c#

```
    private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        double res;
        res = (double)-b / 2 * a;
        if (a != 0 & b != 0)
        {
            return res.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну, а что вернуть, если a и b равны 0?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double res = 0;

    try
    {
        res = (double) -b / 2 * a;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return res.ToString();
    }

    return res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception){return res;}` ? Why?

Comment: @tym32167 упс. Извиняюсь. Забыл про возвращаемый тип.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю проверять значения переданных переменных до расчетов, т.е. на этапе вычисления переменной "res" параметры "a" и "b" не нулевые, переменная "c" не используется в Вашем методе и закомментирована.

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b/*, int c*/)
{
    if(a == 0) return "Can't divide by zero!";
    if(b == 0) return "0";
    double res = (double)-b / 2 * a;
    return res.ToString();
}
```